# wordpress docker image and nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to use docker-compose to create dynamic and fast development environment and I want to use nginx to route all services. This is my configuration:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
        - 80:80
    volumes: 
        - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
```

**nginx conf.d**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://wordpress:80/;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header      Host $host;

    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, it is always trying to move from http://localhost to http://localhost:8080

What should I do?

Comment: do both wordpress and nginx listen on :80 ports or is it just nginx?

Comment: Can you explain what doesn't work? What do the logs say?

Comment: thanks for response!
when i visit http://localhost, I got=> 502 Bad Gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the main issues to address in your sample code:

- Both `nginx` and `wordpress` Docker images listen on port `80` by default. So you should map `wordpress` to a different one. For example `8080`
- All the images will not be able to see each other unless you set up a network for them.
- Update `nginx` configuration to remove the port for `wordpress`. Being in the same network they see each other usin their host names only (so their image name)
- Had to change the way you declare the volumes used by `wordpress` and `mysql` images

So this is what I suggest to have:

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
        - 80:80
    volumes: 
        - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - backend

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - backend

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend

volumes:
  wordpress:
  db:

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://wordpress/;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header      Host $host;

    }
}
```

You can check more details about networking in Docker Compose in [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Comment: thanks for response!
with this configuration, when I visit `http://localhost`, I got => 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Okay, I updated the config in my answer to fix your issue